# Can the definite integral of zero valued function be non-zero?

Tags: probability-theory, distribution-theory, sampling, monte-carlo, sampling-theory

I am trying to understand the Importance Sampling Technique (IS) for rare event simulation. I use the [this tutorial](https:///web.mit.edu/6.454/www/www_fall_2003/gew/CEtutorial.pdf). On page 5, it is written:

"...That is, let g be another probability density such that $g(x) = 0$ $\rightarrow I_{{S(x)\geq 0 }}f(x) = 0 $ "

Moreover, for simplicity I attach the [image: capture from the above tutorial.]

Comment: I think the implication should be read "if $g$ is zero, then $I f(x)$ is zero" not "$g$ is zero, so $I f(x)$ is zero." Does that clear up the confusion?

Comment: Thank you. This is it, exactly. I later understood it myself. Again thanks for your time.